# Flash error while display:block of DIV

Tags: flash, css

I have one flash object inside one div.
It works fine when it loads.

Now what I do is , I set style="display:none;" of Div on one buttons click and on another button's click I set its style="display:block;".

So when it is set to  style="display:block;", it will give me below error and will not load flash:

> “A script in this movie is causing Adobe Flash Player to run slowly.
>   If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive. Do you
>   want to abort the script?”

Why it happens?
Is there any workaround for this?

Regards,
Sagar

Comment: @xFortyFourx :: thanks, it works perfectly. Now it is not throwing that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the reason, I'll suggest a work around which should work. Create a css class

`.hide { display: hidden; }`

Add this class to your `<div>` when clicking button1, and remove this class when clicking button2.